# VirtualBox Headless - Linux

Tags: virtualbox

I have Virtualbox installed on a machine that I want to run headless.

If I ssh into that machine I'm able to run

VBoxHeadless --startvm "WindowsXP" &

and everything runs great.

I want to run the guest headless.

I put the above command into

/etc/rc.local

but it doesn't spark up, after I restart.

I've written a bash script that starts the guest too and tried putting a reference to the bash script into rc.local but it does't work.

What am I doing wrong? Doesn't rc.local run commands after all the init.d scripts have run?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com. To answer tersely: you'll want to enable logging to see what's failing and fiddle with your run level until your headless guest starts successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run VBoxHeadless as the same user that you used to create the setup. Have you done that?

You can use the  su command for this

```
su - <username> -c 'VBoxHeadless --startvm "WindowsXP"'
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows users its the same idea.

C:\Program File\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe --startvm "uuid|name" --vrde off

More info can be found in:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless